# SKLearn: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument n_splits

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use SKLearn (version 0.18.1) as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=100)
```

But I get this strange error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b8dd4f5596be> in <module>()
----> 1 kfold = KFold(k=5, random_state=100)
      2 results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
      3 print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k'
```

I've consulted the docs here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

and `n_splits` does look like a parameter I should be able to pass...

Any idea what's going on here / how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your version of sklearn? You maybe looking at the docs for a more recent version than your installed one, you could just change to `kfold = KFold(k=5, random_state=100)` which should work

Answer (score 7):

Open your terminal (cmd) and try these before you try to import the sklearn.

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

or if you have anaconda installed

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

or

```
conda update conda 
conda update scikit-learn
```

Also make sure your have numpy and scipy:

```
pip install numpy 
pip install scipy
```

**Restart** the python shell after installing scipy !

Comment: For conda `conda update conda` and then `conda update scikit-learn` works.

Comment: i modified my answer including this

Comment: Had a similar problem under conda (same error message, but different function).

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your Scikit-Learn version, try to check it and look for the right documentation ([here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/support.html#documentation-resources)):

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

Or download the lastest version with `pip install -U scikit-learn`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried updating my Scikit Learn, even after updating I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Check the version of your sklearn and the correspondent documentation version.